# SQL Server TDE - how to tell when complete?

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption, tde

Is there a way to tell when a database is completely encrypted when using SQL 2008 TDE? I.e.,

ALTER DATABASE mydb SET ENCRYPTION ON

The only way I can think of is to keep trying to detach mydb. It won't detach until all pages are encrypted.  However, I'd like to have a cleaner way that does not involve detaching?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this information can be found in [`sys.dm_database_encryption_keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677274.aspx).

`encryption_state = 3` indicates the database and logs are encrypted. `encryption_state = 2`  means  Encryption in progress in which case you might want to also look at the `percent_complete` column.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.  I also came across this article for anyone else that needs this information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677274.aspx

Comment: Interesting: percent_complete goes to 100 long before encryption_state changes. So is it complete when it reaches 100 percent, or is it complete when encryption_state changes?

Comment: @Neilw - Not sure what it does in that time interval. I'd assume when encryption_state changes though.

Comment: I tried encrypting a 50GB database. It went to 100% complete in about 4 minutes. But encryption_state did not change to 3 until about ten minutes.

Answer (score 0):

old, but I'll just place it over here. pay attention on "percent_complete"

SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) DbName,
encryption_state EncryptState,
percent_complete,
key_algorithm KeyAlgorithm,
key_length KeyLength,
encryptor_type EncryptType
FROM sys.dm_database_encryption_keys;